# how to read a list of tuples in Python

Tags: python, list, readlines

all, I am learning `Python`, and I am wondering how to read a list of tuples, which stored in a `txt` file, as in the following case:

I have a `txt` file called `scores.txt` with the following format:

```
('name1', 8)
('name2', 2)
('name3', 4)
...
```

Now I want to read `scores.txt` into a list say `scores`, so that I can sort the scores in descending order, and do some further processing. I am wondering how to do that.

This is a practise for maintaining a high scores list stored in a `txt` file. A function is needed for reading the scores from the file, and appending a new score each time the function is invoked. The list of scores needs to be sorted before saving back in the `txt` file (`score.txt`). If `score.txt` does not exist before hand, it will be created first. I borrowed a piece of code somewhere for reference and had a working solution is:

```
def high_score(score):
    """Records a player's score and maintains a highscores list"""
    # no previous high score file
    try:
        with open("high_scores.txt", "r") as f:
            high_scores = [ast.literal_eval(line) for line in f]
    except FileNotFoundError:
        high_scores = []

    #add a score // Do current stuff for adding a new score...
    name = input("What is your name? ")
    entry = (name, score)
    high_scores.append(entry)
    high_scores.sort(key = lambda x: -x[1])
    high_scores = high_scores[:5]       # keep only top five

    # write scores to high_scores.txt
    with open("high_scores.txt", "w") as f:
        for score in high_scores:
            f.write(str(score) + "\n")
```

The problem for me was in how to convert the strings stored in `high_scores.txt` to `int` for saving the `(name, score)` tuple in `high_scores`. And it has been resolved by using `ast` module's `literal_eval` utility function.

Comment: store it in a better serializable format ie `json.dump(scores,file_handle)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import ast

with open("scores.txt") as inf:
    scores = [ast.literal_eval(line) for line in inf]

scores.sort(key = lambda x: -x[1])
```

Comment: good solution ... although Im sure he is generating his "scores.txt" ... the better answer is probably to use a more slurpable format